# Creating multiple 'tables' in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

I'm new to PouchDB. Now I know how to create DB and how add docs in it. But unlike MySQL, I can't create tables here. One option is to create multiple PouchDBs, which doesn't seem a good idea. I don't want to use CouchDB or something like that.

All I want to use is the localStorage. So say if I have 3 tables in MySQL:

1. users
2. messages
3. positions

How would I structure the databases so that I can efficiently use `find` (Query by index) to find the data for a particular table? And is it also possible to define column types like we define in MySQL?

There's something explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066753/pouchdb-structure), but the accepted answer suggests using CouchDB, which I don't want currently. I think it's possible merely by localStorage.

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463488/is-creating-multiple-pouchdb-databases-on-the-same-application-considered-bad-de

Comment: Okay. I followed this. Now I'm stuck with views part and (I'm trying map/query mentioned here: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_database) getting this type of error: https://www.reddit.com/r/CouchDB/comments/420xf1/im_not_to_couchdbpouchdb_and_im_having_a_hard/

Comment: Possibly it is the path issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this plugin https://github.com/pouchdb-community/relational-pouch. It does exactly what asked -- creates DB schema with multiple tables. It comes through with certain limitations. For example, there is no a direct way now to use `find` on types, i.e., you'll need to search for all objects and filter by type:

```
db.find(selector).then(function (data) {
   return db.rel.parseRelDocs(type, data.docs);
});`
```

Also, there might be some potential issues with performance if you create deeply nested structures (async relationships might be helpful).

In general, I believe these issues should not be stoppers with smart design or simple schema.